# Change Permissions on Registry key via Command line

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I am trying to edit this registry key via the command line - been searching around for ages but can't find anything.

Really stuck at the moment so any help would be appreciated a lot. I do not mind using PowerShell or anything that calls a third party tool - just want to change it via the command line.

The reason is that local Administrators have Read only rights by default. I want to change this to Full Control. I can do it in the GUI in 2 seconds but command line is another matter.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{323CA680-C24D-4099-B94D-446DD2D7249E}\ShellFolder
```

Comment: Similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/712392/change-registry-permissions-via-command-line-batch-file

Answer (score 10):

There is an excellent rundown of how to do it in PowerShell [here](http://powertoe.wordpress.com/2010/08/28/controlling-registry-acl-permissions-with-powershell/).

Essentially, you can use `Get-Acl` and `Set-Acl` in PowerShell like you would for any other path.

```
$acl = Get-Acl HKLM:\SOFTWARE\stuff
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule(
    "Domain\user", "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")

$acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
$acl |Set-Acl -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\stuff
```

Comment: thanks for that - the problem I face is that if I am an administrator and I want to change the permissions on a key that has Administrators as READ - it will say access denied....really annoying. I will try the powershell thing out and come back. System is also Read so can't use psexec to do it.

Comment: @lara400 Then you need to take ownership of the key before you can assign `write` permissions. Nothing in the world will let someone with only `read` make modifications. That defeats the purpose of the `read` ACE. I suggest that you open a new question asking for to take ownership of a registry key in PowerShell.

Answer (score 6):

Does [RegIni.exe](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/03/11/how-to-change-registry-permissions-with-regini-exe-vbscript.aspx) meet your needs?  You can write a RegIni script that changes the permissions, and then call RegIni with the script as a parameter.

For example, if you wanted only administrators to have full access to that key, the script would look like this:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{323CA680-C24D-4099-B94D-446DD2D7249E}\ShellFolder [1]
```

Though presumably you would also want to grant the system access to the key, and perhaps read-only access to everyone else, in which case the security suffix would be

```
[1 8 17]
```

You can find the security suffix numbers in this table:

```
1  - Administrators Full Access
2  - Administrators Read Access
3  - Administrators Read and Write Access
4  - Administrators Read, Write and Delete Access
5  - Creator Full Access
6  - Creator Read and Write Access
7  - World Full Access
8  - World Read Access
9  - World Read and Write Access
10 - World Read, Write and Delete Access
11 - Power Users Full Access
12 - Power Users Read and Write Access
13 - Power Users Read, Write and Delete Access
14 - System Operators Full Access
15 - System Operators Read and Write Access
16 - System Operators Read, Write and Delete Access
17 - System Full Access
18 - System Read and Write Access
19 - System Read Access
20 - Administrators Read, Write and Execute Access
21 - Interactive User Full Access
22 - Interactive User Read and Write Access
23 - Interactive User Read, Write and Delete Access
```

And it goes without saying that you should have a good backup before playing with this for the first time, and maybe practice on a dummy registry key to avoid any unfortunate accidents.